# Running CS:GO in Virtual Box giving an Engine Error?

Tags: virtualbox, graphics-card, virtual-machine

Everytime I try to launch the Steam game CS:GO in the windows 8 virtual machine I set up with virtual box, I get the following error:

> Your graphics hardware does not support all features (CSM) needed to
>   run this game.
>
> Device info:
>
> Marked unsupported: 0
>
> Supports PCF sampling: 0
>
> Driver Name: "Microsoft Basic Render Driver"
>
> Vendor ID: 0x1414, Device ID: 0x008c
>
> DriverHigh: 0x00060003, DriverLow: 0x25804407
>
> DXLevel 95, MinDXSupportLevel: 90, MaxDVSupportLevel: 95

My host graphics card is GeForce GTX750Ti 2GB GDDR5 so it shouldn't be a problem. Is there maybe a way to give the VM access to the card? I appreciate all help and suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Do you have the VirtualBox Extensions installed on the host, and the Guest Tools installed in the guest? does the guest have 3d rendering enabled and vram set to max?

Comment: I do have the guest tools installed, 3d rendering enabled, and have enough vram but I don't have VirtualBox Extensions installed, what is that?

Comment: they are closed-source extensions to virtual box. see here for more details: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see a lot with people gaming in Virtualization Software is that they do not take into account the DirectX version. I don't know what version of Virtual Box you are running, but they only support up to a certain version. I think what's happening here is that your version only supports DirectX 9.5 and CSGO probably requires DirectX 10 or 11 in order to run.

Comment: I just checked the CS:GO page and they said that you only need DXlevel 9

"Grafik: Video card must be 256 MB or more and should be a DirectX 9-compatible with support for Pixel Shader 3.0
DirectX: Version 9.0c"

Comment: Okay, just to confirm could you open start menu and type `dxdiag` and press enter. Then select `system` tab then check the DirectX version number under `System Information`? 

Don't worry your card will definitely not be a problem.

Comment: Okay I have done that and it says DirectX 11

Comment: Sorry I should have specified to do that in the VM not your host. Is that what it is in the VM? Also did you allocate enough resources to the VM to meet CSGO requirements? You probably need to allocate 2GB of VRAM to the VM.

Comment: No that is the version in the VM, and yes I have allocated 2048mb ram and also 256 mb for the video card.

Comment: 256MB for the video card still sounds super low I would up it to at least 1GB if possible. CSGO probably requires 256MB, but that doesn't include the OS itself.

Comment: It seems like the maximum option I have here is 256mb

Comment: I have always used VMware over Virtualbox so I am not familiar with their software, but I would be willing to assume that 256MB isn't enough for the OS and Game to run. I would also look for some kind of toolset or something to install. I don't know virtualbox, but VMware tools is something often needed with VMware.

Comment: Yeah I have that, its called Gues tools in virtualbox, I will try to use VMWare workstation now, I'll see if it fixes anything.